# How to round edges on a Macbook with only trackpad? 3.2

Tags: bevel, smooth

I am new to Blender, but have had no luck finding any answer online as to how I can bevel and round an edge, corner, whatever, with only a trackpad on a Macbook.

Comment: you should be able to do it with a trackpad: Ctrl B then move your finger on the trackpad and use the "+" and "-" of the numpad, you can also change the parameters in the Operator box

Comment: @moonboots OMG you are a lifesaver!!!! it worked! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with a trackpad: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> then move your finger on the trackpad and use the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> of the numpad to increase or decrease the number of segments. You can also change the parameters in the *Operator* box (bottom left of your 3D view).